# libgdx game doesn't load textures on return to the app from "recent apps menu"

Tags: libgdx, textures

I noticed a bug in my libgdx game. Every time the user presses the devices back button, the app exits, and on return to the app from the "recent apps menu", the app doens't load textures. Where textures should be, only black squares appear. I also noticed that the on launch loading time is much shorter. Have anyone here experienced a similar problem

Comment: don't use the `static` keyword.

Comment: hmm. I am not sure I understand. What exactly shouldn't be static?

Comment: Nothing should be static. Well except for a `final static int` member or a static helper method perhaps. But in general you should not use the `static` keyword when writing code, that would defeat the OOP (and horribly come back at you at Android).

Comment: You are losing openGLES context, are you using unmanaged textures? Look into AssetManager. There are many valid reasons to use the static keyword. You just have to think about it within the application lifecycle.

Comment: using non-static class for Assets did the trick

Comment: as mentioned here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets static assets causes such problems. use asset manager and do not use static assets textures etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your textures in your Gamescreen. So when you create a new Gamescreen, you also load resources. For example:

```
public GameScreen(YourGameClass game) {
this.game=game;
resources = Resources.getInstance();
resources.loadGame();
```

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I did it with non-static Assets class that holds assets. Your approach looks good to so I will mark it as accepted.